# A Good Book for Mathematical Probability Theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am from mathematical background, and I always hated the way they teach elementary probability theory in schools without giving any clue about measure theory.

I want a theoretical book in probability theory, which starts with measure theory
and defines everything in mathematical terms. I am also not looking for a measure 
theory book. If there is such a book that instead of giving only an intuitive introduction
to probability theory, it rather defines everything in details, I would be really grateful
to know it.

I would be happy to hear about any reading experience. Being exact in mathematical 
language and maybe exercises.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Read *[Probability Theory and Stochastic Processes with Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8189938401)* by Oliver Knill.

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely read *[Probability and Measure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118122372)* by Patrick Billingsley. The book introduces the probability theory simultaneously with the measure theory -- there is not any division like this: first measure theory, then probability theory. The language of the book is clear and understandable, but still rigorous. The book is rich in examples -- after every theorem, definition etc., there are usually two or three of them. Each section ends with a bunch of exercises to which there are hints and notes at the end of the book.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Probability with Martingales](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521406056), which I found to be very helpful for self-study. It's a short read but nevertheless concise and uses measure theory to introduce the basic concepts of probability theory.